# How to use Image and material together in the shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

This is my texture shader program

```
 version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

 struct Light {
   vec3 direction;     
   vec3 ambient;
   vec3 diffuse;
   vec3 specular;
};

 struct Material {
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
}; uniform Material material;

uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform Light light;
in vec3 FragPos;  
in vec3 Normal; 
in vec2 TexCoord; 
uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
 {  
   vec3 ambient = 0.2 * (light.ambient * material.ambient );

  // diffuse
  vec3 norm = normalize( Normal );
  vec3 lightDir = normalize( -light.direction );
  float diff = max( dot( norm, lightDir) , 0.0 );
  vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * material.diffuse;

 // specular
 vec3 viewDir = normalize( viewPos - FragPos );
 vec3 reflectDir = reflect( -lightDir , norm );
float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * material.specular;
vec3 result = ambient + diffuse + specular;
FragColor =  texture( texture1 , TexCoord )  * vec4( result , 1.0 );
```

}

Everthing works as expected.
my question is that if i don't send any image data the objects render black and i will have situations where a object will have no texture attached to it.

Is their any way in glsl to solve this problem or should i send a bool varible to the shader and apply if condition

Comment: bind white empty texture to those .... or use different shader or use uniform to detect no texture and in such case use `FragColor =  vec4( result , 1.0 );` or you can detect no texture by passing color of the rendered face then use  `FragColor =  uniform_color*vec4( result , 1.0 );`

Answer (score 0):

For every aspect of material you have to modify your texture in different way, for example if you have color absorption elemt you have to change color based on this value and you do something like this for every aspect in material, check if texture exists, if it doesnt, just dont render it